# How do I restart a view controller from the press of a button?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, viewcontroller

I have a button named 'RETRY'. What code can I put in the

```
-(IBAction)Retry:(id)sender
```

that will make the view controller restart.

I do not want to know how to restart the app just the view controller

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Can you define "restart"?

Comment: once the button 'Restart' is pressed, then the entire view controller goes back to how it began when it was originally loaded.

Comment: Can you pop the view controller and push a new one?

Comment: sounds like you need to re-architect your design. Have a `loadView` method that will generate your screen or fill your controls with data etc. when the screen is loaded and call this function in your retry method. Please note method names should start with a lowercase letter

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin apart from changing 1 or 2 things, that worked. I put all the code (plus some changes) from the viewDidLoad into the restart part thanks a lot.

Comment: @Lapis glad it helped, I added it as an answer. Please upvote and mark it as top answer so others will know it solved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to re-architect your design. Have a `loadView` method that will either:

- Create your UI elements and add them to the screen
- Passes in your data to the elements that are already in place

Call this method inside your `viewDidLoad` so it runs when the screen loads. Now when you want to "Restart", either call this method and have the data updated or delete all the subviews and call this method to have it redrawn.